# DbUpdateConcurrencyException during update of entities with many to many relation

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm currently struggling with a DbUpdateConcurrencyException in a project involving EF core in .NET.

I have 2 entities User and Room + join-entity UserRoom.
The rules I am trying to implement are :

- A User can be part of many Rooms, and a Room can have many participants (many-to-many relation).
- A User can own many Rooms, but a Room can only have 1 owner at max (one-to-many relation).

Here is what I have on EF core side for those entities:

```
   public sealed class User
   {
       public Guid UserId { get; set; }
       public required string FirstName { get; set; }
       public required string LastName { get; set; }
       public required string Pseudo { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }
       public List<Room> Rooms { get; } = [];
       public List<UserRoom> UserRooms { get; } = [];
       public List<Room> OwnedRooms { get; } = [];
   }

    public sealed class Room
    {
        public Guid RoomId { get; set; }
        public required string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public Guid? OwnerId { get; set; }
        public User? Owner { get; set; }
        public List<User> Participants { get; } = [];
        public List<UserRoom> UserRooms { get; } = [];
    }

    public sealed class UserRoom
    {
        public User User { get; set; } = null!;
        public Room Room { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

With configurations as follow:

```
internal class UserEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
  {
    builder.ToTable(nameof(User));

    builder.HasKey(x => x.UserId);

    builder.Property(x => x.FirstName)
        .HasMaxLength(30)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.Property(x => x.LastName)
        .HasMaxLength(30)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.Property(x => x.Pseudo)
        .HasMaxLength(30)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.HasMany(x => x.Rooms)
        .WithMany(x => x.Participants)
        .UsingEntity<UserRoom>(
           builder => 
           builder.Property(e => e.CreatedAt).HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()"));
  }
}

internal class RoomEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Room>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Room> builder)
  {
    builder.ToTable(nameof(Room));

    builder.HasKey(x => x.RoomId);

    builder.Property(x => x.Name)
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.HasOne(e => e.Owner)
        .WithMany(e => e.OwnedRooms)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.OwnerId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
  }
}
```

My problem occurs when an already persisted user tries to create a room :

```
Guid newRoomId = user.CreateRoom(name, isActive, participants);

using var transaction = await DbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);
try
   {               
     DbContext.Users.Update(Mapper.Map<Infrastructure.Entities.User>(user));

     await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

     await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
   }
catch (Exception)
   {
     await transaction.RollbackAsync(cancellationToken);
   }
```

The user.CreateRoom code:

```
public Guid CreateRoom(string name, bool isActive = true, List<User>? participants = null)
{
  var newRoom = Room.Create(name, this, isActive: isActive, participants: participants);
  OwnedRooms.Add(newRoom);
  return newRoom.Id;
}
```

The DbUpdateConcurrencyException prevents me from saving those changes to the DB.

I can't understand where the concurrency comes from since I'm only adding a Room entry and setting a reference to it for the User.

There are no other processes/requests involved with the user that could be trying to update him in DB at the time I hit this endpoint of my API.

Could I have some help understanding the origin of the exception?

And maybe advices or ideas on what I could try next to resolve this issue please?

I have consulted this [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#resolving-concurrency-conflicts) and many others to find a clue on what I am doing wrong but couldn't figure it out yet.

Comment: What versions of .Net and EF Core are you using? Why do you need the user transaction?

Comment: EF core 8 and .NET 8. You can forget the transaction, it serves no real purpose at the moment, I added it for futur changes and its presence doesn't change anything to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core's Optimistic Concurrency: EF Core uses optimistic concurrency by default, meaning it assumes that concurrent updates to the same data are rare. It tracks original property values and compares them with database values before saving changes. If any values have been modified outside of EF's knowledge, it throws the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` to prevent data corruption.

Missing Context Attachment: The `newRoom` object is created, but it's not explicitly attached to the `DbContext`. This means EF might not be aware of its existence until `SaveChangesAsync()` is called.

`OwnedRooms` Navigation Property: The `OwnedRooms.Add(newRoom)` line modifies the navigation property of the existing user object. However, without proper context attachment, EF might not detect this change, potentially leading to the concurrency exception.

Your code might look like this , try this :

```
public Guid CreateRoom(string name, bool isActive = true, List<User>? participants = null)
{
  var newRoom = Room.Create(name, this, isActive: isActive, participants: participants);

  // Explicitly attach newRoom to the context
  DbContext.Add(newRoom);

  // Add newRoom to the user's OwnedRooms collection
  OwnedRooms.Add(newRoom);

  return newRoom.Id;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I gave a try with your proposition and it indeed resolved the exception issue.
It also creates more questions because I am actually trying to learn DDD, and User in this case is the aggregateRoot, so only adding the Room the the DbContext bugs me as I thought I had to make all changes on the User for it to be reflected by EF core on the DB.
Maybe my comprehension of DDD is also lacking or I'm not doing it the right way with EF core...
If anyone has advices on this aspect , I am all ears!

Comment: I would advise you to look into the working of EF and its state management as well as the tracking mechanism. Trying visiting (https://dotnettutorials.net/course/entity-framework/) . If you are trying to learn DDD I would suggest looking into useful resources, one such is (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_un3PUER8U) try to grasp the concept rather than just focusing on completing codes.